# Any possible way to set radio_button_tag values by a database set value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a radio_button_tag in a form, which holds various values for a persons current availability:

Mike Donnall      o Available   o Out of office   o Vacation

So originally you open the form, and select a value, this then sets the value in the Status table for that Person.

However, there's also functionality to re-open the form and update his present status, perhaps from Vacation to Available.

My question is, is there anyway at all that radio button :checked can be modified to accept a custom method, I have found something in a similar posting, but I want the value foe that radio button to be set to the value in the DB.

My code so far, a stab in the dark perhaps:

View:

```
<% @people.each do |p| %>
    <% @statuses.each do |s| %>
        <%= "#{p.name}" %>
        <%= "#{s.status_name}" -%><%= radio_button_tag ['person', p.id], ['status',     
             s.id], checked?(p.id) %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Helper:

```
def checked?(person)
    @person = person
    @status = Status.find_by_sql(['select status_id from statuses where person_id = ?, @person])

    if @result
 return true
```

end

As you can see Im a bit lost here, but I understand that the method should return the value of the checkbox that needs to be checked, but Im wondering because its a checked functionality, would it only be limited to being a true or false?

So for a persons.status.id check if its true or false.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your helper's SQL that you the following relationship setup between People and Statuses:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

You can access one given person status like this:

```
person = Person.first
person_status = person.status
```

Using that knowledge, your desired view outcome becomes quite simple:

```
<% @people.each do |p| %>
  <p><%= "#{p.name}" -%>
  <% @statuses.each do |s| %>
    <%= "#{s.status_name}" -%>
    <%= radio_button_tag ['person', p.id], 
                         ['status', s.id],
                         (p.status == s) ? true : false %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can of course extract the logic to a helper, but that doesn't seem necessary.

On a personal note, this isn't the way I'd present the information to user, it' too heavy on information in one line. I suggest you put the person's name in a `p` tag, and use a `ul` tag for the statuses.

Comment: that is fantastic and so simple!

Comment: i really dont understand why this kind of functionality is not so well, or even documented at all in books, sites etc...

Comment: you must know your stuff because, heaven knows how you figured it out!!! thanks again

Comment: I suggest you pick up a good book on rails and read it cover to cover. While the framework makes it easy for you to dive in and start coding really fast, understanding the way relationships work and their potential (and lots more) is really worth 2 or 3 days worth of reading :). See http://railstutorial.org/book for a good example. If this solved your problem, the best way to say thanks is to accept it as an useful answer :)